# MUI DatePicker bugging on Thinkpad

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, react-datepicker, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Very weird bug suddenly appeared.

Current "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.9.0" - hasn't been changed for a year.

So suddenly it started bugging out on some windows laptops specifically lenovo.

Not just CSS issue cause HTML inside the component isnt rendered at all.

Any leads or tips are appreciated.[image]

Things i have already checked

- mac - all browsers working
- acer - windows 11 - all browsers working
- lenovo - wind10/win11 - chrome/safari/edge - bugging on each

So i cant figure out this inconsistent behavior and why its happening. Bugs out for 4 months only, working on other. Cant be dependant on OS or just browser.

Comment: If it's only broken on specific hardware, I'm afraid we don't have much chance of debugging this. One thing that does seem plausible: Have you tried resizing the window (on a working device) to the same size as you faulty device? If that reproduces the issue you have somewhere to start.

Comment: @DBS thanks for suggestion. The issue was something related to wrong system time. Its raised to MUI also.